# FB LOGIN -> SERVER_ERROR code 1675030: Error performing query

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova-plugins, facebook-login, ionic-v1

I have an hybrid app on ionic v1. It has facebook login functionality. Have used following plugin for that - https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4. But after August the facebook login wont work and started giving following error - 
Facebook error: SERVER_ERROR: [code] 1675030 [message]: Error performing
query. [extra]: null ionic

When I checked my Facebook developer app review page, it shows -
[image]

It is also showing "user_friends" permission which am not asking for at all through my code - 
    `facebookConnectPlugin.login(['email', 'public_profile'],fbLoginSuccess, fbLoginError);`

For what should I submit it for review or should I even submit it?
The app_id and app_name variables are correct. Am using cordova-android - 6.2.2. Not sure what is causing the error. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to submit your app for review if you only request public_profile and email as these are approved by default.

I also faced the same issue in my ionic-3 app as you face. In my case, The issue was caused because I tried to use a **testing facebook account in which email was not confirmed**.

I confirmed the email and tried again it works now, this may help you.